# To what extent are Human Resources job functions on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Project Management asked if we wanted [this question on HR skill tracking software](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/6639/best-way-to-track-employee-skills). I'm honestly not sure whether something that specific to a job function would be on topic.

On one hand specific job function stuff is out; we can't be a resource for specific jobs. However, HR, like management, is special in that those specific job functions *do* involve general workplace issues.

So, where can we draw a line here?

Comment: This is actually an IT Software question not an HR question.  That should be off topic.

Answer (score 6):

As it is, I don't think it's a good fit. It's a shopping question.

> Assuming the organization is far too large to track this type of information manually (using a spreadsheet, word of mouth, etc.), what is the best way to collect these types of metrics in an automated way?

It basically confines the question to "the best way is some computer software, what's the best software for this?". Answers could be things like

> TrackMySkillz by ABC Inc is excellent!

---

> StaffMetrics is a bit more expensive than TrackMySkillz, but it adds features X Y and Z!

---

> i wrote these cool open-source codes, you should definatley use my prgram! [link]

To quote [their ♦ moderator](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/6639/best-way-to-track-employee-skills#comment7048_6639), Mark Phillips (emphasis mine):

> [...] It sounds like you are looking for a **list of** [...]

Such questions are not a good fit for any Stack Exchange site.

#### So, to actually answer your question:

As long as a job-specific question fits two criteria, I'm fine it:

1. Practical question that can be answered in a reasonable way
2. The question/answer can be relevant to more than the specific job discussed in the question (either an entire job category or an entire industry)

Comment: Yeah, the listiness kills it for me too, I was just wondering more generally where HR fits in here.

Comment: Wow, very helpful.  I just breezed over here to see why that question was closed, cause I didn't quite agree, but this is a perfect explanation, and I totally agree.

Comment: +1 Jim. Great explanation. I didn't see the non-constructiveness until now. I wonder if it could be edited somehow though to make it more constructive, since it does have some raw material to work with.